# Making a formula using paste

Tags: r

I am trying to make a formula using R.

I have the following data:

```
data(iris)
iris <- iris %>%
  select(Species, everything())
```

I am trying to make a `formula` based on the colnames. I would like it such that the formula looks like `formula <- y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4`. I can use the following to get the X variables.

```
paste("X", seq(2:ncol(iris)), sep = "")
```

How can I paste the y ~ before them and add the `+`? I can use `collapse` but I would like the `~` and the `+` in the same formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `reformulate`

```
reformulate(paste0("X",  head(seq_along(iris), -1)), "y")
#y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted but very close! `reformulate(paste0("X", seq(2:ncol(iris))), "y")` this seems to work and you always seem to have an answer to my questions! Thanks again!

Comment: @user113156  I updatred the answer, I got confused by your usage of `seq(2:ncol`

Comment: is `seq_along()` a better method? "Column1" in the data is the "Y" variable. Both `seq` and `seq_along` work. Which is more suitable in general practice?

Comment: @user113156 I use `seq_along`, there would be some performance improvement, but not that much

Comment: One additional question which is related. How can I rename the columns such that the columns are called Y X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 ? I am trying with various paste options but not getting anywhere

Comment: @user113156  You can use `paste` with `collapse = ' '` i.e. `paste(c("Y", paste0("X", 1:4)), collapse=" ")`

Comment: The following: `data(iris)
colnames(iris) <- paste(c("Y", paste0("X", 2:4)), collapse=" ")` puts everything into the first column.

Comment: If you assign colnames without the collapse should work: `colnames(iris) <- paste(c("Y", paste0("X", 1:4)))`

Answer (score 4):

It will be simple if we first rename and rearrange the columns using the below or something similar

```
library(dplyr)
df <- iris %>%
        select(Species, everything()) %>% 
        rename_all(~paste0("X", seq_along(.) - 1)) %>%
        rename(Y = 1)
```

We could then use `reformulate` like

```
reformulate(names(df)[-1], names(df)[1])
#Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4
```

We can also use `paste0` to create a string as per preference and then use `as.formula`

```
as.formula(paste0("Y ~ ", paste0(names(df)[-1], collapse = " + ")))
#Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4
```